# Can we do clustering over several columns in a huge dataframe?

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I have a dataset stands for customers retail sales data, it includes `customer ID`, `Age`, `purchases frequency in the 24 month`, `purchase frequency overall`,`how many goods cust purchased in the 24 month`, `how many goods cust purchased overall`.

I want to cluster it using Kmeans only based on `Age`,`purchase frequency overall` and `how many goods cust purchased overall`. Then, assigning `labels` for each customer ID, is that possible?

By the way, I have encounter a memory error if I use Python Agglomerative Clustering. I guess the dataset is quite large, but I don't find any solutions. Any one can give any suggestions?

Comment: Generally yes, whether it works well one can't say based on this information

Comment: What kind of extra informations you need ? @deemel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, clustering with respect to those three features is possible. The problem with Kmeans is that you have to pre-determine the number of clusters and that clusters should have a rather simple form for Kmeans to work properly.

I would strongly suggest first plotting your data, e.g. with some pair-plot library, e.g. in [python](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) or in [R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/pairs). That way you get a feeling of whether clustering really makes sense.

There are more powerful clustering algorithms than Kmeans, a very basic and very popular one would be e.g. [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html), which doesn't require a pre-determined cluster count but does require a density parameter.

If you have memory problems, you could either use clustering algorithms that are known to scale well (e.g. [BIRCH](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.Birch.html), but *without* the final clustering step (parameter `n_clusters` set to None)) or think of compressing your data first. There are many [possibilities](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41019-016-0022-0).

Comment: I have met another problem is how to use kmeans algorithm to cluster dataset based on 'weighted' variables ? Since not all variables considered in the clustering have the same importance.